# Is there a way to access an insecure HTTP api request in GITHUB?

Tags: github, github-pages

My repo on GitHub consists of a simple API data pull.
But GitHub throws an error as the data request is made on an insecure HTTP link rather than an HTTPS link.

Is there a workaround that, like maybe asking GitHub to override the security and accept the data from the HTTP link anyway?

Answer (score 2):

> Accept data from http anyway?

No, any call to GitHub API is always redirected to https

```
$ curl -L -i http://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs                             
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-length: 0
Location: https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs
Connection: close
```

So using https is, for GitHub API, the only option allowed right now.